# MySql Trigger - Compara valores con otra tabla con mensaje

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, trigger

Muy buenas a todos,

Estoy aprendiendo SQL, estoy usando mysql workbench y tengo un problema relacionado con el trigger.

Tengo dos tablas, una de ellas se llama DireccionEntrega con atributos: idDir, idT, idPed, Road, Pais, Region. La otra se llama Cobertura con atributos: idCob, idProv, Pais, Region.

Quiero crear un trigger para la tabla DireccionEntrega para que cuando se inserte valores en ella, los valores de País y Región de la tabla DireccionEntrega, deben estar en la tabla Cobertura. Si no, se muestra un mensaje de error.

Te muestro cómo creé el disparador:

```
create trigger Comprobacion before insert on DireccionEntrega 
for each row
begin

    if not exists(select Cobertura.idProv, Cobertura.Pais, Cobertura.Region from Cobertura, Proveedor, LineasPedido where
                    Cobertura.idProv = Proveedor.idProv and Proveedor.idProv = LineasPedido.idProv)
        then
        signal sqlstate '45000'
                set message_text = 'Error insert...';
    end if;
end;
```

No sé lo que está sucediendo, pero no funciona.

Las expectativas del trigger son las siguientes:

```
insert into DireccionEntrega(Pais, Region) values ('España','Oeste')
```

Debe de funcionar e insertarse en la tabla ya que la información de España, Oeste está en la tabla de Cobertura

```
insert into DireccionEntrega(Pais, Region) values ('Portugal','Este')
```

No debe de insertarse en la tabla de DireccionEntrega debido a que la información de Portugal, Este no está en la tabla de Cobertura. Por tanto, debe mostrar un mensaje de error como se muestra en el trigger:

Error insert...

Espero que podais resolverme esta duda porque no se porque no funciona dicho trigger. Cualquier cosa que necesites de información, pregúntamelo y te lo digo sin problemas.

Muchas gracias y un saludo.

Comment: ¿Y eso no lo puedes resolver con una  `FOREIGN KEY`?

Comment: @DavidJP No puedo introducir una `FOREIGN KEY` dentro de la tabla de DireccionEntrega debido a que las restricciones para crear la base de datos me impiden realizar esa relación.

Comment: @DavidJP Aquí tienes el código en dbfiddle. [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/xBrdsxqu).

Answer (score 0):

Prueba así:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS comprueba;
create trigger comprueba
  before insert on DireccionEntrega 
  for each row
  begin
      DECLARE r INT;
      select COUNT(*) INTO r 
        from Cobertura, Proveedor, LineasPedido
        where Cobertura.idProv = Proveedor.idProv
        and Proveedor.idProv = LineasPedido.idProv;
      if r>0 THEN 
        signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'Error insert...';
      end if;
end;
```

Comment: no me funciona eso debido a que el conteo que hace siempre es mayor que 0. Lo he podido arreglar al final. Lo adjunto para que lo veas. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

El código del trigger es el siguiente:

```
create trigger Comprobacion before insert on DireccionEntrega 
for each row
begin
     if not exists(
          select Cobertura.Pais, Cobertura.Region 
            from Cobertura
              join Proveedor ON Cobertura.idProv = Proveedor.idProv
              join LineasPedido ON Proveedor.idProv = LineasPedido.idProv
              join Pedidos ON LineasPedido.idPed = Pedidos.idPed
              where Cobertura.Pais = NEW.Pais and Cobertura.Region = NEW.Region
              and LineasPedido.idPed = NEW.idPed
        ) then
        set @message = CONCAT(
           'Error insert... no existe la cobertura de: ', 
            NEW.Pais, ' y ', NEW.Region, ' para el proveedor del pedido ', NEW.idPed,'.'
        );
        signal sqlstate '45000'
                set message_text = @message;
     end if;
end;
```

Gracias!